# unforget bluetooth device osx 10.9.5

Tags: bluetooth

I accidentally told my Mac laptop to forget my bluetooth speaker. Now I can't undo the 'forget device'? Can i reset it so i can reconnect my wireless speaker?
I have tried to find a reset button in settings but I can't find one?

Answer (score 1):

Forgetting a bluetooth device should just mean that it no longer automatically connects. Just do whatever you did to connect the first time if you want to reconnect. There are probably instructions that came with your bluetooth speaker.